# Scala pattern matching on Map with arrow symbol

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

1. `List("a"->1, "b"->2) match { case List( k->v ,_*) => println(k) }`
   error: not found: value ->
2. `List("a"->1, "b"->2) match { case List( (k,v) ,_*) => println(k) }`
   success
3. `Map("a"->1, "b"->2) match { case Map( (k,v) ,_*) => println(k) }`
   error: value Map is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member

Could you explain why that the left hand side succeeds using arrow `->`; while at right hand side the `->` failed.
If I change it to real type `Tuple` (k,v), then it success.
However, failed again if using `Map` .
I cannot image Scala didn't implement `unapply` for Map?!

---

EDIT:
what I thought is `::` can be use in pattern matching; so could `->` .
OK , now `->` is a method , so cannot be matched. 
Scala is not intuitive.

Comment: What do you feel unapply shouild do on a Map? For a List, there's an ordering so it's clear what to match. For a Map, there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `->` syntax is just a shorthand to create a tuple. So `'a' -> 1` actually returns something of type `(Char, Int)`. Since it is not a type, you can't match that syntax. Match the tuple instead.

Also for the Map, I'm not sure there is an extractor for that. You generally need and `unapplySeq` method, which is defined as returning a sequence. The very syntax _* means passing a sequence of parameters, and map is kind of by definition an unordered structure. You can always use `toSeq` to get a sequence of tuples.

Comment: So do you mean , for `->` to work in pattern matching, I need to implement a `->` class with unapply ?

Comment: Yes, I did that long time ago in my util package: `type ->[A, B] = (A, B); object -> { def unapply[A, B](t: (A, B)) = Some(t) }`

Answer (score 1):

Version 1. of your code works in 2.13.

It seems `->` with `unapply` was added in 2.13.0, namely in [PR Add -> alias for Tuple2 to Predef](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6304). The `->` symbol is a value alias for `Tuple2` case class companion object, see [Predef source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/fe0df69fb011637ba294d3b17f3b8054a1d512e0/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L178).

Comment: From the [`Predef` source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/fe0df69fb011637ba294d3b17f3b8054a1d512e0/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L178): `val -> = Tuple2`. As [`Tuple2` is a `case class`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/fe0df69fb011637ba294d3b17f3b8054a1d512e0/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L24), that means it has an auto-generated (and undocumented) companion `object` with the expected `unapply()` method. Thus `->` is a reference (read _alias_) to said object.